# Retrieve the records from SAP HANA database is slow in JAVA

Tags: java, hana

The performance of the application to retrieve the records from SAP HANA ResultSet is slow.

To verify the performance I created the following scenario and tested. I used MySQL and SAP HANA for comparison purpose.

Created the same table in both MySQL and SAP HANA databases and generated the same data in the table in both databases.

Created report using MySQL database and time taken to publish data into elastic search – 22 milli secs

Created report using SAP HANA database and time taken to publish data into elastic search – 19441 milli secs

The following code is taking more time

```
while(rs.next()){

<!--code to fetch the the records !-->
 rs.getString("actorId");
}
```

The same code is being used for both MySQL and SAP HANA database.

I have put log file statements to see the time taken for execution and observed SAP HANA is taking more time to fetch and process the records from ResultSet.

Comment: 22ms ? How many rows you are testing/fetching ? Is elastic on the same host ?  How do you know that getString() is taken more time ? How do you benchmark your code ?

Comment: Elastic server is on same host. Processing 300 rows. Problem is not with MySQL, with SAP HANA Resultset, it is taking almost 20 seconds where as MySQL is taking 22ms only

Answer (score 0):

HANA database works best when table is created is COLUMN TABLE

You can find a sample [CREATE COLUMN TABLE script](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/create-calculated-column-in-sap-hana-database-table.aspx) on given sample. Then you will not need an index for a half million record in selectivity is high on table columns

It will be better to test the query performance on HANA database by directly executing the query on database, you will get execution statistics easily regarding database performance.

Otherwise, the problem might be related with connection too